# 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type '<< error type>>'

Tags: ios, swift, git, types

We use git. After I used git pull, I run it and get two errors like this

[image]

I have import MIBadgeButton_Swift.
I have a storyboard with a MIBadgeButton object.
I drag a connection to my view controller.
error:1.Use of undeclared type 'MIBadgeButton'
      2.'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type '<< error type>>'
But other guys can build project success. So why I am getting this error and how to remove this error?

Comment: Check the class definition for MIBadgeButton - this class doesn't seem to exist

Comment: The guy fo my group can run project sucessfully..Same project..And MIBadgeButton is project of Github，we use pod to manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the button you are using placed in a local framework? if so try to rebuild the framework first, if you are not sure try next steps.

If you say that everybody else can run the project, it seems that your build folder got mess. You can try this steps in order to clean it

1. Remove app from device
2. In Xcode within your project press `cmd` + `alt` + `shift` + `K`
3. Clean Derived data of the project (Go to window > Projects > Don't press Delete, press the arrow next to the path, remove all files and folders from there)

Now, when you will press start, a new and clean build will be made

**Update**
you mentioned you use pods to manage your project, do a `pod outdated` - to check if there are any pods outdated, you are interested in the one with the button mostly, if so do an update on it