# Xcode: swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I have problem with this function:

```
func isSmallDevice() -> Bool {
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height <= 1136 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Basically if I comment these lines build will succeed and if not it will fail with following error:

**Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1**

No other errors or warnings are shown and note that I am not calling this function. I also tried quitting Xcode, deleting derived data and cleaning project.

Comment: where are you calling this? also try to add an return false for the > case

Comment: I am not calling it at all. Tried calling it, does not change anything.

Comment: you could try to deep clean your project, it might help - you could refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912683/weak-cannot-be-applied-to-non-class-type-error-type/35912875#35912875 , i don't see any problems in your code

Comment: same problem have quit my xcode multiple times and even delete the derived data but no help.